# AJAX - Is there an open source app that allows users to select photos from a set of photos?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I'm trying to create a little application that allows users to multi-select a couple of photos.

The idea is that we would show the user a grid, with about 50 photos in it, and they would be able to select 10 of those photos for use elsewhere on my website.  These 10 selected photos may appear together in a separate module, or whatever.

Does anyone know of code that can help me kickstart this type of functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding it yourself, best way to implement this is using JqueryUI's Selectable Interaction

Here is the link to their official Demo/Example. 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid

Press and hold Ctrl to multi-select

Answer (score 0):

You could start modding one of these to get going.

- [Top 14 jQuery Photo Slideshow / Gallery Plugins](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/)
- [Smashing Magazine 30 Scripts For Galleries, Slideshows and Lightboxes](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/)
- [57+ Free Image Gallery, Slideshow And Lightbox Solutions](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)

Though I think you'd be better off writing this yourself.